# CSS in my website isnt working properly for some elements but it works fine on my other pagees with the same element

Tags: html, css

I have a website that I am making and for one page a lot of CSS functions dont work. I always have it in an external style sheet, but I have tried putting it in the document but it still doesn't work.  The same code works on other pages of my website just not this one.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
</head>


<body>

<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" 
onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
    <a href="index.html">Home</a>
    <a href="allpic.html">Purchase Page</a>
    </div>




<div class="main">
    <span style="font-size:50px;cursor:pointer" onclick="openNav()" 
class="menuFade">&#9776;</span>

    <div class="batteryHill-container">           <!--this doesn't work-->
        <img src="images/batteryHill.jpg" class="checkout-img-resize" 
style="width:1000px;">   <!--only works because of the style tag included-->
    </div>
    <div class="checkout-batteryHill">     <!--doesn't work-->

    </div>

</div>



<script>
function openNav() {
        document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "340px";
        document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "340px";
    }

    function closeNav() {
        document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0px";
        document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "0px";
    }
</script>
</body>




//the CSS

.batteryHill-container {
padding-top: 100px;
max-width: 1000px;
}
.checkout-img-resze {
max-width: 100%;
}
.checkout-batteryHill {
width: 50%;
float: right;
background-color: black;
}

//there is more but I wont include it because there is too much, ill just 
//give you the CSS included in this document at the moment.
```

Comment: Have you tested them with using `!important` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a typo in your CSS. You have defined a rule for `checkout-img-resze` instead of `checkout-img-resize`.

Comment: Thanks Mayank this worked, But do you know why the <checkout-batteryHill> doesn't work, the background-color isn't becoming black?

Comment: Possibly the div is of height `0`. Try adding some children to the div or specify the height explicitly.

Comment: The background colour changed when I added some text. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use absolute URLS when defining a style sheet.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://www.example.org/css/main.css">
```

Comment: I have never has an issue with just linking to a file instead of a URL

Comment: .... You need to use full urls when picking a style sheet. if you go to a page thats in asub directory e.g. example.org/help-section/ then what happens is your stylesheet tries to go to /help-section/main.css which it obviously doesnt exist in..... Just because you have never done something doesnt mean you shouldnt start.....

Comment: I wasn't saying that. Just saying that I have never had an issue with it before. This isn't any major project just a hobby and won't be too big so I'm not worried about sun directories at this point. and I don't even have a URL.

Comment: then refrence the folder that your site is in or use the c:mydopcuments/site/css etc

Comment: Oh thanks, I have never noticed that before, so I just have "main.css" it is looking in my current directory but if I define "/main.css" then it will always look in the root directory?

Comment: Exactly mate.it will alwasy change the pth to your current directory if its not defined